# Declare a function which accepts a tuple parameter with a generic type

Tags: generics, f#

Here is a code snippet which I have written:

```
let Foo (a : (int * int) seq) =  ();;
val Foo : seq<int * int> -> unit

let inline Bar (a : (a' * int) seq) = ();;
let Bar (a : (a' * int) seq) =
--------------^^
stdin(8,15): error FS0039: The type 'a'' is not defined
>
```

My intention was that `Bar` should be a function to which I can pass tuples with different types like `(string * int)` or `(float * int)`. Why can't I define my function this way?

Comment: Since type `'a` isn't used anywhere else in the function, you can use wildcard `_` and let the type checker infer the generic type: `let inline Bar (a : (_ * int) seq) = ()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tick (') comes before the type variable, not after it (that is, you want to use `'a`, not `a'`).

Also, you are unlikely to need to use `inline` in your declaration.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a function explicitly generic using <> to introduce the generic type.

```
let Bar<'a> (a: ('a * int) seq) = ()
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need a type annotation here? This is cleaner and has the same type:

```ml
let Bar a =
  for c, d in a do
    printfn "%A, %d" c d
```